# Virtual Pagination on Dynatree

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-dynatree

I am trying to use virtual paging on the dynatree. I have lot of nodes & sub-nodes which are loaded on an on-demand basis. But the requirement is even on the on-demand loading, virtual pagination should trigger. i.e. when the user scrolls down mode nodes gets added dynamically. Is there any way I can attain this functionality.

Thanks,
Anirban

Comment: There is way to achieve this, are you looking for the solution?

Comment: it will good if you could share the solution . Thanks, Anirban